# numpy matmul does not compute matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following 3x3 matrix H and 3x1 matrix point. Calling the matmul function simply returns the original point. Why and how can I fix this?

```
H = np.array([[1, -1.07059445e-13,7.30192357e-11],[-1.07136486e-13,1,1.19101035e-11],[-2.88444403e-16,9.61481343e-17,1]])
point = np.array([443.8957214, 198.19000244, 1])
np.matmul(H, np.transpose(point))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because H is approximately an eye matrix (identical matrix)

```
H = array([[ 1.00000000e+00, -1.07059445e-13,  7.30192357e-11],
          [-1.07136486e-13,  1.00000000e+00,  1.19101035e-11],
          [-2.88444403e-16,  9.61481343e-17,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

and multiplying H by point is equal to point:

```
import numpy as np
H = np.array([[1, -1.07059445e-13,7.30192357e-11],[-1.07136486e-13,1,1.19101035e-11],[-2.88444403e-16,9.61481343e-17,1]])
point = np.array([443.8957214, 198.19000244, 1])
out = np.matmul(H, np.transpose(point))
```

as you can see here, difference between output and pint is too small.

```
out - point
array([ 5.18411980e-11, -3.56408236e-11, -1.09023901e-13])
```

Comment: I am used to the identity matrix ([1 0],[0 1]) returning a copy of the matrix it multiplies, I suppose there is a broader category of values that do that then.

Comment: Because non diagonal elements are near to zero. So by multiplying them to each other, output  is approximately near to input. If you want to see more detail of output, increase digit resolution in python.